# Имя собственное в родительном падеже

Tags: имена-собственные

Как будет правильно звучать в родительном падеже Сидорова Мария Петровна? Я считаю : Сидорову Марию Петровну.

Answer (score 2):

Родительныйпадеж отвечает на вопросы: нет кого?чего?, а "Сидорову Марию Петровну" - это винительный падеж (отвечает на вопросы: вижу кого?что?). Так что в Вашем случае: нет кого? Сидоровой Марии Петровны

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!